# Restrict API gateway access to specific IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

How can I restrict an API deployed using [serverless](https://serverless.com) to only be accessible to specific IAM users?

I see that I can use [IAM authorizers](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-aws-iam-authorizers). However, it doesn't say how can I make it restrict it to specific users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html).

There are 2 parts to this:

- You set the authorizer to aws_iam. This makes the API gateway endpoint no longer public. The endpoint expects IAM based authorization to happen.
- Then you configure the policy for the individual IAM users (or other entities) to have invoke permissions to that API. This is what allows individual entities to invoke that API.

Comment: I tried this, but any other IAM role can also access my gateway. not sure if theres additional configurations you made.